# How to get from Cuzco, Peru to El Calafate, Argentina in 1 day (24 hours)?

Tags: transportation, peru, argentina, patagonia

All flights I see on kayak.com take me through Santiago, Chile or Buenos Aires, Argentina to get to El Calafate, Argentina. But they take more than a day.  Is there a quicker way?

Comment: Are you going on a specific, problematic day? I can't find any flights taking more than one day. The fastest connection I found with my first search is 15:00 with change in Lima and Buenos Aires.

Answer (score 5):

I tried a [flight for next month](http://www.kayak.com.au/flights/CUZ-FTE/2014-02-12-flexible) on there, and the times range from 13h 40 to 46h 20(!) - quite a difference.

Once the page is loaded for your dates, on the left choose more filters, and then play with the stopover and leg times - reduce them and you'll start to see the shorter flights.

South American airlines often work on a hub-spoke model, like the US - so for example, many inter-city flights in Argentina go via Buenos Aires.  Similar with Lima in Peru.  And indeed, the 13h 40 flight flies to Lima, then Buenos Aires, then down to El Calafate.